# Why doesn't Heroku show the complete IP chain in the x-forwarded-for header?

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

My Gunicorn and Python Flask based Heroku app receives a GET request through a proxy server. The expected behaviour with regard to header information would be that the x-forwarded-for header contains two ip addresses (proxy ip, originating ip).

The used proxy definitely adds that header information. I confirmed it through a simple flask app that basically works similar to the Heroku app but runs on a cheap VPS hosting package for testing purposes.

How can I access the complete ip chain in Heroku? Is Heroku doing anything to the raw request before it reaches the app? I also replaced Gunicorn and Flask with Waitress as a test, but to no avail. That setup shows the same behaviour.